# Retrofit HTTP Get with dynamic URL

Tags: android, annotations, http-get, retrofit

My Interface is like this

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET("/api/session/{id}")
void getSession(
         @Path("id") String id, Callback<JsonObject> callback
);
```

But I keep getting, `No retrofit annotation found.` When searched why this error, the most common answer was that the request was expecting **@Body**. But I don't want to give a body its part of my **url**.

Exception that I am getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AuthApi.getSession: No Retrofit annotation found.
(Parameter#1)
at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.methodError(RestMethodInfo.java:123)
at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parameterError(RestMethodInfo.java:127)
at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.parseParameters(RestMethodInfo.java:450)
at retrofit.RestMethodInfo.init(RestMethodInfo.java:134)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:294)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
END ERROR
```

Comment: Can you add more information - code that is invoking getSession method and exception details.

Comment: Please see edit. 
and I am getting sessionId from prefrences.

Comment: @ShahrozKhan91 have you found an answer to this problem?  I am facing similar.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky sorry man, i did find a solution. But i don't remember what it was. As far asi remember it had something to do with the imports, please check them.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with Retrofit using SimpleXML Converter.

The problem was an import, I had:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Path;
```

instead of:

```
import retrofit.http.Path;
```